# themes on intellij idea

Tags: themes, intellij-15

I'm using intellij idea 15 community with dracula theme but on files html I see several green line in the code How can I disable them?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Fanally I found the solution:

Go Language Injections Setting and cofigure the language

Answer (score 0):

Change it here :

```
View->Quick Switch Themes Scheme->Look and Feel-> Default/Darcula
```